# Keeping track of failed login attempts

Tags: php, security, session, passwords, brute-force

This question is essentially language-agnostic, but in my case I'm using [PHP](http://php.net/) for anyone who wants to know.

I would like to keep track of the number of failed login attempts a user had, so that after `X` failed attempts a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is displayed. The only purpuse this would have is preventing brute-force attacks. It doesn't have to be an extremely secure way, just annoying enough to delay whoever is brute-forcing.

I was thinking of creating a session variable `$_SESSION['failedLoginAttempts']` and to increase it every time a failed login attempt is detected. The attacker could still alternate browsers or delete his cookies to keep going, but this would make him (i.e. whatever tool he's using to perform the brute-force) waste a couple of seconds more for every attempt, so the number of attempts would be greately lowered.

From a couple attacks from second to a couple attacks per minute would be ideal, then the attack would be negligible.

Is this approach correct or am I missing something? Also, what's the best practice in these cases?

Comment: They would probably skip around to different user names too. Maybe log by IP as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're best off logging this in the database attached to the user ID. This is because a determined attacker isn't going to be using a web browser for brute force; it's pretty straightforward to build a script in most any language that would make repeated login attempts and ignore the cookies entirely, or reset the cookies after every attempt.

Comment: That's true... but wouldn't resetting the cookies every single time would take enough time (maybe even less than a second) to stunt the attack?
And if it's not, maybe it would be more effective to log the IP of the attacker, and prevent any login attempt form that IP for a couple of hours

Comment: If they're using a custom script, resetting cookies takes a negligible amount of time (microseconds). You can track by IP or by username, but username is probably more effective. For example, my office has around three hundred people behind a single external IP address. So locking by IP could generate a lot of false positives, where two people behind the same IP logging in at the same time would appear to be an attack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, you are probably right. As long as the defense measure is _not_ blocking the account (therefore impeding the _actual_ owner to access it) but something like a CAPTCHA, tracking by username is the most effective way.

Comment: Now, the failed login attempts should be reset over time. Like a user can mistype their password once today, and another time tomorrow and a week later. You shouldn't force them to have to enter captcha after a month when they just go to login page, just because they had enough failed login attempts in past. So after each successful login, reset the counter to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind if you store your password encrypted in your database.

PHP or MySQL should take the user input and encrypt that.

For example (not real and not safe code)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = " . $_POST['username'] . " AND password " . sha512($_POST['password']);
```

What if your server can take up to 8 Mb data in post requests. That attacker can post 1 Mb as password, Trying to DDOS on the encryption to keep the CPU of the server on high load.

Comment: You should never do something like `password = " . sha512($_POST['password'])`. Instead `select password from table where username = $_POST['username']`. Obviously sanitize user input first. Then compare what's in database to what was posted in the password field running any necessary encryption. You should also have a software firewall and mod_security if on a LAMP setup. mod_security usually helps with large post data attacks, whereas firewall might be a good solution against DDoS. Nonetheless, I find this answer to be irrelevant to the OP's question.